# Is there a better way of manipulating SOAP messages than Jaxws SOAP Handler Interceptor before the message gets to the container?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, handler, interceptor

I am currently using the jaxws and apache CXF framework to create webservices using the top down approach.

I am using the SOAP interceptors to add remove SOAP header elements, using SAAJ, before the message gets to the container, and the container maps the SOAP action too the java method.    I am doing this to create Security Token Services (STS) to facilitate a lite implementation of the SAML2 Profile - converting authentication details into portable identities (SAML Authentication Assertions).

I cannot help think there must be an easier way to do this.  Is there a framework that will allow me to manipulate the message with more ease? and if so a tutorial would help.

Many thanks

Comment: If by SOAP Interceptors you mean SOAPHandlers as described in https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html, then yes, I think it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

To change things in SOAP messages you must use SOAP Handlers.
Maybe easier way to do it is changing the way you are securing your web service, if you use a WS-Security way of doing things, our container will work with it fine, and you don't need the handlers anymore.